# break the loop when cells isempty or isnan in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

[image: coordinates matrix]

> Firstly I'm new to matlab programming. Here is my doubt. I would like to break the loop when the cells in this matrix is either empty or a NaN. Matlab suggesting not to have isempty and isnan in same line. The error i get is "Attempted to access coordinates(10,1); index out of bounds because size(coordinates)=[9,8].". I'm messing up somewhere, could someone help on this? Thanks.

```
    n_b=0;
    n_nodes=0;
    for j=1:2:10
        for i=1:1:10
            if (isempty(coordinates(i,j))) or (isnan(coordinates(i,j)))
                break
            else
                disp(coordinates(i,j));
                n_nodes=n_nodes+1;
            end
        end
        n_b=n_b+1;
        if (n_b==4) % break at four columns
            break
        end
    end
```

Comment: Since when is `or` valid syntax in MATLAB? Also, looks like you're working with a `double` array, not a `cell` array... `double` arrays can't have "empty" elements, unless the entire array is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this lines:

```
for j=1:2:10
    for i=1:1:10
```

You are trying to access coordinates that do not exist. Try this:

```
for j = 1:2:size(coordinates,2)
    for i = 1:size(coordinates,1)
```

This will always stop before the matrix ends.

Also, delete the `isempty()` check from your condition, as it never fulfills, together with the `or` which is not a valid MATLAB syntax (should be `||`).

Here is how you full code should look:

```
n_b = 0;
n_nodes = 0;
for j = 1:2:size(coordinates,2)
    for i = 1:size(coordinates,1)
        if isnan(coordinates(i,j))
            break
        else
            disp(coordinates(i,j));
            n_nodes = n_nodes+1;
        end
    end
    n_b = n_b+1;
    if (n_b==4) % break at four columns
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: I find the loop is not breaking when the cells is NaN. I tried going step by step using F10 to check it. n_nodes at the end should correspond to the number of (x,y) coordinates. Could you please recheck?

Comment: Have you tries yo use this suggestion? It works just like expected.